# How to programmatically select and deselect multiple dates in calendar control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to programmatically select and deselect multiple dates in calendar control in asp.net?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();

protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Day.IsSelected == true)
        {
            list.Add(e.Day.Date);
        }
        Session["SelectedDates"] = list;
}


protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
        {
            List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
            foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
            {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(dt);
            }
            list.Clear();
        }
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
        {
            List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
            foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
            {
                Response.Write(dt.ToShortDateString() + "<BR/>");
            }
        }
}
```

The above code only selects the multiple dates, how can we deselect the dates one by one in above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To removed the currently selected date

```
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
```

To remove one date at a time

```
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Remove(Calendar1.SelectedDates[0]);
```

Or to clear all the selected dates at once

```
Calendar1.SelectedDates.Clear();
```

See all the available methods of the **[SelectedDates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.selecteddatescollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: How can i remove the currently selected date from a set of dates?